# What other edition of D&D should I buy for someone who loves the first edition?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

My boyfriend (31) LOVES D&D and has been playing it since the first edition came out. He doesn't have any other editions, but I wanted to surprise him with another one. He's a real perfectionist and hasn't ever really finished the first one (from what he has me understand). He always goes back and changes his character and just isn't quite satisfied with his team BUT adores the game. D&D was his favorite gift ever, so I wanted to upgrade him. I have no idea which version would be best for him, though.

Comment: “Shopping” questions and other recommendation requests are off-topic, but can be asked on any one of a number of [role-playing games discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). For more information, see [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic, Revisited.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited)

Comment: Auto-generated comments from close votes are a bit cold. I certainly want to help, as do many of the others on the site I'm sure. But due to the nature of questions like these and the history they have on the site, it's very difficult for us to help and still keep the answers consistent with the site's purpose. I'm not as convinced that including why he likes certain games will get the question opened again either. If you get enough rep to join us in chat, we would be happy to brainstorm some ideas there. But aside from that, the suggested forums just suit your needs better than we can.

Comment: Hey @Laura, Zachiel's comment is on spot. Questions like these are off-topic here on SE:RPG, but you are free to discuss that topic on the chat with others. If you haven't already, you could take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the structure of this site.

Comment: It's not obvious to outsiders, but it's a fact that different editions of D&D are different *games*. An "upgrade" won't actually be an upgrade and may not be appreciated.

Comment: The Players' Handbooks from *all* of the other editions (or at least 2e, 3.5e, 4e, and 5e; you can probably skip 3e unless you *really* want to be thorough) might make an interesting gift because of the way it would let you compare and contrast the different games. But it only really works if you do all of them together -that's what keeps it from being an "upgrade"- and this can get pricey.

Comment: @Laura Since you have some rep now, you can join us in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) and discuss your matters! We will happily help you with your concerns there!